# Auto submit form in Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to submit automatically after click on label , I used Jquery but it did'nt work.

this is my Jquery Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#tt").click(function () {
    $("#demo-form2").submit();
});
```

When T tested using alert function it works fine :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#tt").click(function () {
    alert("Bye! You now leave p1!");
});
```

tt is the id of label that I clicked on 
This is razor code :

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index2", "Commande", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left", role = "form", @id = "demo-form2" }))
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                         <table>
                        <tr>

                            <th id="tt">
                                Code Article
                            </th>
                        </tr>...

}
```

help ,

Comment: is that the right id of your form? Could you please share the rest of the code? Also if that is the only form in your page you can try $('form').submit();

Comment: Check the form id properly !

Comment: Can you see the form id when you inspect the form ?

Comment: I add some html code

Comment: No I have multiple form in my razor

Comment: the form id is demo-form2 when I inspect the form Poria

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? maybe the link is broken

Comment: I got error relaed to template , I testes with another form it works but with this specific form did'nt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I am using a input named "submit" in the form.

When I changed the name "submit" jQuery code works fine.